# Wordpress Filter, changing plugin Array

Tags: wordpress, forms, filter

this is my first try on adding a filter to my functions.php. I am trying to overwrite form settings set by a Plugin, depending on what form is used or what page is viewed.

the Array I am trying to overwrite looks like this in the plugin :

```
$form_settings = (object) array(
            'form_title'                    => stripslashes( html_entity_decode( $form->form_title, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' ) ),
            'form_subject'                  => stripslashes( html_entity_decode( $form->form_email_subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' ) ),
            'form_to'                       => ( is_array( unserialize( $form->form_email_to ) ) ) ? unserialize( $form->form_email_to ) : explode( ',', unserialize( $form->form_email_to ) ),
            'form_from'                     => stripslashes( $form->form_email_from ),
            'form_from_name'                => stripslashes( $form->form_email_from_name ),
            'form_notification_setting'     => stripslashes( $form->form_notification_setting ),
            'form_notification_email_name'  => stripslashes( $form->form_notification_email_name ),
            'form_notification_email_from'  => stripslashes( $form->form_notification_email_from ),
            'form_notification_subject'     => stripslashes( html_entity_decode( $form->form_notification_subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8' ) ),
            'form_notification_message'     => stripslashes( $form->form_notification_message ),
            'form_notification_entry'       => stripslashes( $form->form_notification_entry )
        );
        // Allow the form settings to be filtered (ex: return $form_settings->'form_title' = 'Hello World';)
        $form_settings = (object) apply_filters_ref_array( 'vfb_email_form_settings', array( $form_settings, $form_id ) );
```

And my functions.php looks like

```
function maildeponselectcountry() {
    //here comes the new mailadress 
    $form_id = 2;

    $form_settings = array(
        "form_title" => "test"
    );

    apply_filters_ref_array( 'vfb_email_form_settings', array( $form_settings, $form_id ) );

}

apply_filters( 'vfb_email_form_settings', 'maildeponselectcountry' );
```

I am confused by apply_filters_ref_array. What am I supposed to do with that? I really only wanna overwrite the form_to in the $form_settings Array. I would appreciate any hint! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `apply_filters_ref_array`. That's where the plugin is allowing you to use the filter. You also want to use `add_filter` not `apply_filter`. `apply_filter` is used to setup the data that's allowed to be filtered.

Your function should look something like this:

```
function maildeponselectcountry( array( $form_settings, $form_id ) ) {

    /* not sure what is actually passed here, 
       but if you need to check for the form_id, 
       it might be something like this. The passed array is actually an object 
       because of typecasting. */

    if ( $form_id->id == 2 ) {
       // Set the object property value
       $form_settings->form_title = 'test';
    }

    // return the form_settings with or without the updated value (depending on the form_id)
    return $form_settings;
}

// Use add_filter and set the priority.
add_filter( 'vfb_email_form_settings', 'maildeponselectcountry', 10 );
```

EDIT:

Try running this test:

```
function maildeponselectcountry( $form_settings ) {

       return $form_settings->form_title = 'Test';
    }

    // Use add_filter and set the priority.
    add_filter( 'vfb_email_form_settings', 'maildeponselectcountry', 10 );
```

When running that, post the output from the '' so we can see the returned data.

Comment: Oh wow Thank  you so much! It seems like there is a Problem with this part 

` function maildeponselectcountry( array( $form_settings, $form_id ) ) { ` 

it creates a Server Error it says the Page has a Problem. When I take the array away the webpage works again.

Comment: What is the error? Also, you might be able to pass just `$form_settings` instead of `array($form_settings, $form_id)`. I don't have your exact plugin, so testing is a bit difficult.

Comment: Yes I tried just function maildeponselectcountry( $form_settings ) { this is working. But it does not overwrite the array. The Plugin is Visual Form Builder the  free Version

Comment: I did run your test.  It does not give an error but how do I see if it adds the <pre> i do not see it in frontend.

Comment: The Test echo's this:

'stdClass Object
(
    [form_title] => Kontaktformular
    [form_subject] => Kontaktformular ...
    [form_to] => Array
        (
            [0] => test@test.ch
        )

    [form_from] => test@test.ch
    [form_from_name] => ORELL Tec
    [form_notification_setting] => 
    [form_notification_email_name] => 
    [form_notification_email_from] => 
    [form_notification_subject] => 
    [form_notification_message] => 
    [form_notification_entry] => 
)'

Comment: I just updated the test. Try that out and see if the title changes now.

Comment: what I am actually trying to get accomplished is depending on a selectbox, I wanna send the form to different E-mail addresses, I just thaught I try something easy by changing the subject not the title. So it would be form_subject . But that does not work eighter.

Comment: Ah. I'd have to download the plugin and try it. That will have to be a bit later. But my code will start you down the correct path with filters.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I am wondering if I actually could use jquery to get the selected value and then put it in the add_filter function somehow. Oh my questions over questions.

Comment: That wouldn't work very well...mainly because you would need to use jQuery AJAX to pass data to a function - that isn't a filter. I think you're on the right path with the filter...just need to see how the data is being processed in the filter.